# Cannot call 'SetContentView' on new activity - Android Mono

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I've had a search for this problem but nothing seems to help me to solve this particular error I am getting.

I am writing my first Android app and am coming across a java.lang.RuntimeException whenever I call SetContentView on a new activity.

There is nothing in the logcat which helps (an activity idle timeout is all because it falters on the call).

My activity **Login** has a layout set during **OnCreate** which works fine, but any subsequent calls fall over. Here's some code ;)

```
[Activity(Label = "Usage")]
public class Usage : TabActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        //**FALLS OVER HERE**
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Usage);
```

The **Resource.Designer.cs** has a record of my layout:

```
// aapt resource value: 0x7f030002
public const int Usage = 2130903042;
```

...and when I reference that layout by it's **int** value it falls back to the previous activity without hitting any breakpoints in the **Usage** activity.

Anyone got any thoughts or can point me in the direction of a similar post?

Legends!

**UPDATE**

I tried a whole stack of fixes I found on forums etc but nothing would fix this. I put the whole thing on the backburner while I worked on something else, came back to it and now it works...wish I could say what it was that made it work to help others out but I can't explain it! *COULD* have been an update to a new version of MonoDroid?

Comment: PS: Just say if you need to see any more of my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment to Stuart's answer, this problem appears to have resolved itself. I revisited the project all this time later and think that it might have just been a case of cleaning the project and rebuilding all. I have not had this problem since.

Sorry that this is not a detailed answer, I would suggest trying the ol' clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had some issues when working in VS2010 where the resource ids are being not kept perfectly in-sync with the resource files and the java ids.

To resolve these, I generally find the quickest way is to add a new id to one of the layout xml files - this then causes a regeneration or the resources.cs file which then means the app works again.

If that doesn't help, then please post more info about what the message inside the RuntimeException is,

Comment: Thanks Stuart, I'll give this a go and get back to you!

Comment: Hey Stuart, I tried to refresh the resources.cs file but still couldn't get it to work. Put the whole thing on the backburner while I worked on something else, came back to it and now it works...wish I could say what it was that made it work to help others but no joy sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Although it's very late response, but someone who might be getting this sort of error. Wrap it with try-catch and it gives more details about the exception. I spent few hours before figuring out to do that